# How to enable/ disable ListView onItemClickListener on specific items?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am designing a game in which the player has to complete the levels in sequence in order to proceed to the next level. Is there a way to implement this?

I have tried this in my custom ListAdapter

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   if(position==0){ return true;}
   else{return  false;}

}
```

But I'm not able to find a way to work this for more than one level.

Comment: ditch listview, use recyclerview, set click listener in the viewholder#bind, check condition before enabling it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following code inside `setOnItemClicklistener()`

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (listview.getChildAt(position).isEnabled()) {
                    listview.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
```